# Spring: Filtering RESTful responses by user login or token

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I'm writing a SPA in Angular loosely based on their Heroes tutorial. Right now I'm working on its Spring 4 RESTful server.

In my design the results from the server get filtered according to who you are.  That means the server must know from the login what user it is dealing with.

Suppose that my users want a list of their companies.  They ask the server for these by the /myapp/company URL.

- Tom is an ordinary user.  The server returns A and B, what he is entitled to.
- Bud is an ordinary user.  The server returns C and D, what he is entitled to.
- Jerry is an admin, and can see all.  The server returns A through F.

In order to keep Tom or Bud from seeing all companies the RESTful server must be able to tell from the login information -- a token, a cookie, whatever -- that Tom is calling.  Perhaps the token contains the user's ID.

I see a number of web pages discussing the glories of JWT, or using cookies, or Spring Security.  Thorough discussions on configuring your program and filtering URLs according to user role.

What I'm looking for, and not finding, is how to use the login information in the GET or POST handler.  I know how to do this with a server session.  But since a RESTful server should be stateless, I supposedly shouldn't do that.

My question, then, is how do I store a user identifier into such a cookie or token, and how do I fetch it in my RESTful GET, PUT or POST handler?

Thanks, Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question for security configuration. There are certain things you need to take care.

**With Spring Boot**

You have to identify you apis into these categories:

- Login api which will generate security token
- Non-secure apis
- Secure apis

To configure secure, non-secure and login api, you need to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and add these details in "configure" method

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

- login api will return a security token within header it may be any fixed name
  X-Auth-Token or Authorization. Some filter configurations are required which you can refer in reference link for jwt token configuration.
- For any secure api, filter will be added and security token will be looked in headers with same name to validate request.
- If any secure api require role/permission based access then add role based configuration like using @PreAuthorize at method level or in configure method like  .antMatchers("/userPage").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")

[Spring boot jwt configuration sample project](https://github.com/auth0-blog/spring-boot-jwts)

**On Front end**

- Call the login api, on success if token is returned then save this token on frontend in cookie/sessionstorage etc.
- For any secure api call, pass this token in header with fixed name. Everything else will be taken care by spring boot application like token expiration, associated user, its roles

**How to tell frontend, current user has what permissions**

- You can use login api or create some profile api which will return the role/permissions details to frontend. Based upon on this, on frontend the restrictions will be applied.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  However, your advice doesn't meet my needs.  Storing permissions on the browser can be overcome by some clever, malicious user who then gets unauthorized data.  Your server advice is either "store in the session" -- not stateless -- or merely applies a role to the URL access itself.  In my example multiple users, Tom and Bud from above, will ask /myapp/company for company values.  If Tom should somehow ask for Company A and C the server must ensure that only Company A is returned, as Tom isn't allowed Company C.

Comment: You are missing some points here, which i mentioned. APIs will be secured and role based access with custom service for permissible company. Whole authentication will be done on backend side. On frontend, its just to hide non-permissible links for good customer exp (why to show such links which are not permissible/working for user). If user gets the non-permissible links somehow, even then api will not allow that, that will not break any security